# how to access an element from a list in r?

Tags: r

I would like to access an element from a list but I got NULL

```
  > x <- list("b" = TRUE)
  > x
   $b
  [1] TRUE
  > x$b
 [1] TRUE
  > var=c("b","c")
```

I tried this:

```
  > x$var[1]
  NULL
```

Comment: In your example, wouldn’t it be var[[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[[` instead of `$` as `$` would try to literally search for `var` as the `list` name instead of the value stored in the object

```
x[[var[1]]]
#[1] TRUE
```